# FutureWarning: The behavior of `series[i:j]` with an integer-dtype index is deprecated

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

While performing the operation as:

```
y_test = y_test[:-2]
```

I got the following warning:

> FutureWarning: The behavior of `series[i:j]` with an integer-dtype index is deprecated. In a future version, this will be treated as *label-based* indexing, consistent with e.g. `series[i]` lookups. To retain the old behavior, use `series.iloc[i:j]`. To get the future behavior, use `series.loc[i:j]`.

Do I have to use `y_test.loc[:-2]` instead of `y_test[:-2]` ? Will that show same behavior?

Comment: As the warning explains, it depends on what you want. It sounds like you want `loc`, but Pandas is encouraging you to make this specific since it's ambiguous

Comment: y_test.loc[:-2] should work fine for this case.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the Pandas developers plan to remove the lazy indexing for Series objects, potentially to make it consistent with DataFrame objects which must use `.loc` and `.iloc` to avoid indexing along the column axis.  You do not *need* to use the new behavior until you plan to use a version of Pandas that does not support this indexing method for Series objects though you will continue to see the `FutureWarning`.

As an additional note, PyCharm 2022.1.1 and earlier uses this deprecated logic in its pydev helper.  I have not tested the newest version to see if it has been removed.

Comment: It is still present in PyCharm 2022.3 as of Dec. 2022

Comment: Correct as is the use of Series.iteritems over the newly preferred Series.items when using the Python Console and Scientific mode.

Answer (score -1):

First, convert it into an array then try it. As:

```
y_test = y_test.to_numpy()

y_test = y_test[:-2]
```